# I want to return the sum of the numbers of each row of the matrix, but my program returns zero. What is the problem with my program?

Tags: c#

I want to return the sum of the numbers of each row of the matrix, but my program returns zero. What is the problem with my program?

```
public class Row_summer
    {
       
        

       public int[]  summ(int[,] input, int rows, int columns)
        {
            int sum=0;
            int[] sum_of_rows = new int[rows];
            input = new int[rows, columns];

            for(int i = 0; i >=rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j >= columns;j++)
                {

                    sum = sum + input[i, j];
                }
                sum_of_rows[i] = sum;
            }
            return sum_of_rows;
        }

    }
```

I changed all the values to integer but it still returns zero value. I noticed that it exits the loop before completing the loop count

Comment: `>=` instead of `<`

Comment: Also: `input = new int[rows, columns];` this makes `input` an array of all zeroes. You probably want to delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

you use `>=` instead of `<` in the loop condition.

Correct code would look something like this:

```
public class Row_summer
    {
       
        

       public int[]  summ(int[,] input, int rows, int columns)
        {
            int sum=0;
            int[] sum_of_rows = new int[rows];
            input = new int[rows, columns];

            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j < columns;j++)
                {

                    sum = sum + input[i, j];
                }
                sum_of_rows[i] = sum;
            }
            return sum_of_rows;
        }

    }
```

Also, you may want to move `int sum = 0` into the outer loop:

```
public class Row_summer
    {
       
        

       public int[]  summ(int[,] input, int rows, int columns)
        {
            
            int[] sum_of_rows = new int[rows];
            input = new int[rows, columns];

            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                int sum=0;
                for(int j=0; j < columns;j++)
                {

                    sum = sum + input[i, j];
                }
                sum_of_rows[i] = sum;
            }
            return sum_of_rows;
        }

    }
```